# setting configuration variables before initialization of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, initialization

I was setting some global variables (for setting `devise` gem authorization customization). So, I put some file `auth_provider.rb` in the `config/auth` folder where I declare some module MyAuth (in some `myauth.rb` file). The problem is that when this module is called by some file in the `initializers` folder, call it `caller.rb`, so that I had to put in the `application.rb` file

```
config.before_initialize do
      Dir["#{config.root}/config/auth/*.rb"].each {|file|
        require file
      }
end
```

But I don't find it really natural. And, if I put `auth_provider.rb` in the `initializers/auth` folder, then `caller.rb` seems to be loaded before `auth_provider.rb`, so I get some `namespace error` (I presume the files are loaded by alphabetical order). So how, to load the `auth_provider.rb` before `caller.rb` in a more straightforward way ? Should I create some `initializers/0_auth` folder in order to be loaded in first ? (By the way, i want this configuration modular and to keep it clearly seperated from the rest of the 'proper' rails app config variable declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of your initializers is important, you have to name them appropriately (they are applied in alphabetical order). The Rails Guide about this (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) propose to use numbers, so doing something like you proposed:

```
01_auth_provider.rb
02_caller.rb
...
```

is actually a good way.

Comment: thank you ! do you think there is some other way to do that ?What do you think of what I made calling some load in the `application.rb` ?

Comment: Why are you looking for some other way? Even if you import them manually (via a custom script), you'll have to define an order yourself. Using the file names for this may look arbitrary, but the numbers make it very easy for a human to evaluate which script is called first, just by looking at the files in the directory.